# "help()" doesn't return docstring of method when using magical "__getatrr__"

Tags: python

I'm working on a piece of code that uses Pyhton's magical `__getattr___` method to allow for call of 'functions' that are not really defined.
The problem is that `help()` returns the wrong docstring, that of the class, instead of that defined using `__doc__`. I can, however, print the correct docstring.
What must I do to get `help()` working as I want it to do?

Example:

```
class MathOperations(object):

    class VariableFunction(object):
        """This is the standard docstring of the class."""

        def __init__(self, name):
            if name == 'add':
                self.__doc__ = 'Return the sum'

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return self.VariableFunction(attr)

MathOperations = MathOperations()

help(MathOperations.add)
print(MathOperations.add.__doc__)
```

Which gives:

```
Help on VariableFunction in module __main__ object:

class VariableFunction(__builtin__.object)
 |  This is the standard docstring of the class.
 |  
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __init__(self, name)
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data descriptors defined here:
 |  
 |  __dict__
 |      dictionary for instance variables (if defined)
 |  
 |  __weakref__
 |      list of weak references to the object (if defined)

Return the sum
```

I didn't write the original code, but I want to get it running.

Comment: That's what's supposed to happen; `help` gives you the documentation on the *type* of the object: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6f0eb93183519024cb360162bdd81b9faec97ba6/Lib/pydoc.py#L1660; you end up in [`TextDoc.docclass`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6f0eb93183519024cb360162bdd81b9faec97ba6/Lib/pydoc.py#L1213).

Comment: Didn't doubt that this is supposed to happen. My question is: can I change something in the code that ```help``` gives me the desired docstring?

Comment: In your code? You would need to get `VariableFunction` to pass one of [these tests](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6f0eb93183519024cb360162bdd81b9faec97ba6/Lib/pydoc.py#L1654) such that you get the help for the object itself not the class. I'm not sure how you could sensibly go about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `help()` in this case will always print the docstring of the class, the trick is to change the class' docstring programmatically. I found solutions in these SO topics: [How do I programmatically set the docstring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056983/how-do-i-programmatically-set-the-docstring), [doc for __getattr__ defined attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131731/doc-for-getattr-defined-attributes).

So in my case I changed the code as follows:

```
class MathOperations(object):

    class VariableFunction(object):
        """This is the standard docstring of the class."""

        def __init__(self, name):
            if name == 'add':
                self.__doc__ = 'Return the sum'


    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        wrapper = self.VariableFunction(attr)
        wrapper_type = type(wrapper)
        wrapper_dict = wrapper_type.__dict__.copy()
        wrapper_dict['__doc__'] = wrapper.__doc__
        variable_function = type('VariableFunction', (object,), wrapper_dict)
        return variable_function(attr)

MathOperations = MathOperations()

help(MathOperations.add)
print(MathOperations.add.__doc__)
```

And this is the output:

```
Help on VariableFunction in module __main__ object:

class VariableFunction(__builtin__.object)
 |  Return the sum
 |  
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __init__(self, name)
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data descriptors defined here:
 |  
 |  __dict__
 |      dictionary for instance variables (if defined)
 |  
 |  __weakref__
 |      list of weak references to the object (if defined)

Return the sum
```